# Failure in finding the target of a shortcut

Tags: c#, console-application, shortcut

I'm trying to create a little program which retrieves to the user the target filename of shortcut in C#(Console Application).
My code works without errors, but it doesn't giving me the correct result.

This is my code: (took from: http://snipplr.com/view/47974)

```
private static string GetTargetPath(string ShortcutPath)
{
    string pathOnly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(ShortcutPath);
    string filenameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ShortcutPath);

    Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.ShellClass();
    Shell32.Folder folder = shell.NameSpace(pathOnly);
    Shell32.FolderItem folderItem = folder.ParseName(filenameOnly);
    if (folderItem != null)
    {
        Shell32.ShellLinkObject link = (Shell32.ShellLinkObject)folderItem.GetLink;
        return link.Path;
    }
    return ""; // not found
}
```

As I said, the code retrieving me wrong output (an empty string), even if the file is exists.
for example, I tired to get the target file of some shortcut in the path: C:\Users\Admin123\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office\Recent

What can be the cause of this problem? and how can I solve it?

**EDIT**

I tried the same code again and now it works ! Thanks to everyone ! :)

Comment: I believe you need to use COM Interop Services to use the Shell32.dll components successfully.  I've never actually had a reason to use it though so I don't want to point you too far in the wrong direction.  Here is the MSDN article on COM Interops though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645712(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Are you just wanting to know if a file exists or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I see no problems with your code. Tested and it works well.

I created two links: `boot.lnk` and `prestigio_notes.lnk`, both leading to proper files. Their output was:

`D:\Boot1.asm` and `D:\Dokumenty\Android\Prestigio\doc\prestigio_notes.txt` respectively.

This is the code I used (sorry for copy-pasting the function once again, but I want it to be a complete and clear class):

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(GetTargetPath(@"D:\boot.lnk"));
        Console.WriteLine(GetTargetPath(@"D:\prestigio_notes.lnk"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string GetTargetPath(string ShortcutPath) {
        string pathOnly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(ShortcutPath);
        string filenameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ShortcutPath);

        Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
        Shell32.Folder folder = shell.NameSpace(pathOnly);
        Shell32.FolderItem folderItem = folder.ParseName(filenameOnly);
        if (folderItem != null) {
            Shell32.ShellLinkObject link = (Shell32.ShellLinkObject)folderItem.GetLink;
            return link.Path;
        }
        return ""; // not found
    }
}
```

Check that you are referencing proper COM object from the available references list. If it fails, check that you have rights to read from specified location.

Comment: You're right, now my code magically works, .. Thank You Anyway !